# Turtle difference between @base and empty prefix

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

In [RDF-Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/), what is the difference between using a `@base` prefix and empty prefix (with just `:`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@base` is not a prefix declaration, but a... well, a base declaration. It declares a document's base location, against which all *relative IRIs* are resolved. `@prefix :` is a prefix declaration (in this case for the default or empty prefix), against which all *prefixed names* with an empty prefix are resolved.

Even though they are both ways to write down an IRI, a relative IRI is not the same thing as a prefixed name. They follow different syntactical rules.

For example:

```
@base <http://example.org/base/> 
@prefix : <http://example.org/prefix/> 

<name> rdf:type rdf:Property .
:phone rdf:type rdf:Property .
```

In this example `name` is a relative IRI. The base declaration will be used to resolve it to the absolute IRI `http://example.org/base/name`.

`:phone` is not a relative IRI, but a prefixed name (with an empty prefix). The (empty) prefix declaration will be used to resolve it to the absolute IRI `http://example.org/prefix/phone`.

Easy way to tell the difference between an IRI and a prefixed name in Turtle: the former has `<>` brackets around it.

Comment: From your answer I see, that there is a difference in syntax, but I keep asking myself, which one should I use, and why do both of them exist?

Comment: @hoijui one reason is that base URIs give a mechanism to use relative paths in the data, and then use an _external_ base URI (instead of whatever is declared in the file) to resolve them. This can be useful for things like hosting the same data in multiple locations.

Comment: so `@base` is preferable, as it allows for more flexibility, and has no down-side to it?